# PHP - Curl MultiRequest Timeout

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I'm using this following multiRequest function and sometimes the problem occurs, that the loop at

```
do {
curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);
```

seems endless and reach my php execution limit.
I thought it had sth to do with the DNS Lookup, so I'm calling the ip addresses directly now.

But this problem sadly still occurs sometimes... Is there a way to set a timeout for each handle to avoid an endless loop? What else I could do to fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array())
    {
        // array of curl handles
        $curly = array();
        // data to be returned
        $result = array();
        // multi handle
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        // loop through $data and create curl handles
        // then add them to the multi-handle
        foreach ($data as $id => $d) {
            $curly[$id] = curl_init();
            $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
            curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            // post?
            if (is_array($d)) {
                if (!empty($d['post'])) {
                    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
                }
            }
            // extra options?
            if (!empty($options[$id])) {
                curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options[$id]);
            }

            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
        }
        // execute the handles
        $running = null;
        do {
            curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        } while ($running > 0);
        // get content and remove handles
        foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
            $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
        }
        // all done
        curl_multi_close($mh);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to update my libcurl version to make it work :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can set an individual timeout on a handle with CURLOPT_TIMEOUT (and other options).
2. You can have your own timeout and just remove the handle from the multi handle (which thus cancels the operation) at any given time you think enough is enough.